# Vue does not recognize bootstrap properties

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/):

```
  <b-container fluid="xl">
     <h2>Example</h2>
  </b-container>
```

When using a "fluid" prop, Vue.js gives me a warning in the console:

```
[Vue warning]: Invalid prop: Type check failed for "fluid" prop. Boolean expected, got String with value "xl".
```

In bootstrap-vue [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#containers-b-container) the "fluid" prop is known to be valid.

How to make Vue.js recognize bootstrap props without generating warnings?

Comment: The code you provided looks correct, the value used in `fluid` is a string.The problem might come from another place Have you declared `fluid` anywhere else in code?

Comment: No, "fluid" only exists in this part of my code.

Comment: Could you check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/AnkitZore/a0wu9Lhx/) i have created basic container. I could not produce your error.

Comment: I also couldn't reproduce in jsfiddle, local only

Comment: Are you using the latest bootstrap-vue version?
Because you need to use at least the version `v2.2.0` in order to get the fluid prop as a string ([commit related to this change](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/commit/234e2820686db9c6feecabd857d3a941df298cbe)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting this error because you might be using an older version of [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/).
You should update your [bootstrap-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue?activeTab=versions) to [2.2.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue/v/2.2.0) or [newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue) (**2.23.1** is the latest at the time of my answer).
There might be breaking changes between the version you are using and the newest but it will be better for you in the end and you will be able to use the fluid prop as a string (as stated in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#containers-b-container)).

- [v2.2.0 Changelog with mentions to the b-container
  update](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/changelog#v220)
- [Initial commit related to this change (the one mentioned in the
  changelog)](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/commit/0e318f4755e65eb569dcc579938d0d72c02abd62)
- [Latest commit related to this
  change](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/commit/234e2820686db9c6feecabd857d3a941df298cbe)